# Accessing a variable used in another class, Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, variables

Please be gentle, I am new to Java but I would really like to learn. I have here a simple app (experiment) with a webview and three buttons. Each button loads another address into the webview.

As you see at each button, right after the "View.OnClickListener()" I am referencing again and again to the "myWebView" variable, but without this I get the "myWebView cannot be resolved" error message. I am sure this is not the right way :D

How could I access the "myWebView" variable created in the above classes from inside the "setOnClickListener" function?

Thanks!

```
package com.example.cinemagrandmall;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/home.html");
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Buttons();
    }


        private void Buttons() {
        Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
        Button rezervari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rezervari_btn);
        Button locatie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locatie_btn);

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/home.html");              
            }
        });

        rezervari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/rezervari.html");             
                }
            });

         locatie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {              
         myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/locatie.html");              
                }
            });
         }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare several types of variables for your class (from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)):

> - Member variables in a class—these are called fields.
> - Variables in a method or block of code—these are called local variables.
> - Variables in method declarations—these are called parameters.

You are creating the second type, so your myWebView variable is only accessible in the blocks of code where it was declared.

Change your variable from second type (local) to first type (class field), and it will be accessible everywhere in your MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //declared as class field, will be accessible in every method of the class
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialise it here
        myWebView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        //rest of your code
}
```

It would be a good idea to learn the basics about classes, scope, etc., you can check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html), [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/CatalogJava.htm), [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0100__Class-Definition/Scopeclassdemonstratesfieldandlocalvariablescopes.htm).

Comment: Thank you for all the kind answers, I got now the idea. Will continue to learn some more about the basics, starting with classes...:)

Answer (score 1):

make `myWebView` a member of the `MainActivity` class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       WebView myWebView;

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/home.html");
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Buttons();
    }


        private void Buttons() {
        Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
        Button rezervari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rezervari_btn);
        Button locatie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locatie_btn);

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/home.html");              
            }
        });

        rezervari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/rezervari.html");             
                }
            });

         locatie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {              
         myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/locatie.html");              
                }
            });
         }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field for your class so you can reuse it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    // now you can use myWebView anywhere in your methods
    // without having to redefine it every time

}
```